# How to recycle IIS Express without stop Debugging?

Tags: c#, debugging, iis, iis-express

I came across with a problem  related to recycling the iis and statics variables (more specifically: dictionaries) problems in which the statics Dictionaries lose their values ​​and keys when the pool is recycled.

But this problem can only simulate in the production ambient. In development I can't simule :(

I had the idea of ​​using IIS Express to simulate debugging the problem, but to do this I need to recycle the IIS Express without stopping to debug.

Is there a way to do this? If not, does anyone have any idea how I can simulate this problem to fix it?

Answer (score 12):

The apppool will recycle if you modify your App\Web.config. Unfortunately you'll have to do it via explorer/notepad, as Visual Studio will tell you to stop debugging if you try.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that this is not possible.  Part of the point of recycling is to stop and start the process, which breaks the debugger attachment.

In terms of solving your static variables issue, consider perpetuating this type of data to an external store like Redis.  It's a great way to preserve data that has to live across app pool recycles and is extremely fast and stable.